# 'corMatch' function in package monitoR results in error message [pkg-monitoR]

Tags: r

I've worked through the great tutorial 'A short introduction to acoustic template matching with monitoR'

I'm now attempting to detect calls using spectogram cross correlation within a 30 second sample field recording. The function corMatch is returning the following error...

'Error in !all.equal(template@t.step, t.step, tolerance = t.step/10000) : 
  invalid argument type'

What have I done wrong?

I've used the following code:

```
survey <- readWave('20180901_160000.wav', from = 64, to = 64.5, units='minutes')
mtemp1 <- readWave('mew.wav')
mtemp2 <- readWave('mew2.wav')
mtemp1.fp <- file.path(tempdir(), "mtemp1.wav")
writeWave(mtemp1, mtemp1.fp)
mtemp2.fp <- file.path(tempdir(), "mtemp2.wav")
writeWave(mtemp2, mtemp2.fp)
survey.fp <- file.path(tempdir(), "survey2018-09-01_160400_ACDT.wav")
writeWave(survey, survey.fp)
mt1 <- makeCorTemplate(mtemp1.fp, frq.lim=c(6,9), name='m1')
mt2 <- makeCorTemplate(mtemp2.fp, frq.lim=c(5.5,8.5), name='m2')
MewTemps <- combineCorTemplates(mt1, mt2)
MewTempScores <- corMatch(survey.fp, MewTemps)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/jonkatz2/monitoR/issues/2 - the sampling rate of the survey wave file doesn't match the sampling rate of the template.

You can use either `seewave::resamp` or `monitoR::changeSampRate` to resample one to make them match